# Groovy executing shell commands

Tags: groovy

Groovy adds the `execute` method to `String` to make executing shells fairly easy;

```
println "ls".execute().text
```

but if an error happens, then there is no resulting output.  **Is there an easy way to get both the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) and [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)?**  (other than creating a bunch of code to create two threads to read both inputstreams, using a parent stream to wait for them to complete, and then convert the strings back to text?)

It would be nice to have something like;

```
 def x = shellDo("ls /tmp/NoFile")
 println "out: ${x.out} err:${x.err}"
```

Comment: This [link](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/08/executing-shell-commands-in-groovy.html) is useful. Shows how to run shell command with cURL demo.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself;

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = 'ls /badDir'.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "out> $sout\nerr> $serr"
```

displays:

`out>  err> ls: cannot access /badDir: No such file or directory`

Comment: In case you also need to set **Environment Variables** to this process, make sure to wrap the command in shell. For example, running a Perforce command with env vars: `envVars = ["P4PORT=p4server:2222", "P4USER=user", "P4PASSWD=pass", "P4CLIENT=p4workspace"]; workDir = new File("path"); cmd = "bash -c \"p4 change -o 1234\""; proc = cmd.execute(envVars, workDir);`

Comment: @paul_sns unrelated to the OP question, but I think modern JVMs handle uncontended synchronization just fine. So StringBuffer is unlikely to degrade performance in thread- or stack-confined scenarios .

Comment: The docs say that we should be using waitForProcessOutput() - "To wait for the output to be fully consumed call waitForProcessOutput()". Source: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#consumeProcessOutput(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: @srikanth the waitForProcess() output docs also say "Use this method if you don't care about the standard or error output and just want the process to run silently" - I want the output

Comment: sout and serr might not be available even after the waitForOrKill. Tested using an assert instead of a println. Docs say: "For this, two Threads are started, so this method will return immediately. **The threads will not be join()ed, even if waitFor() is called**. To wait for the output to be fully consumed call waitForProcessOutput()."

Answer (score 67):

`"ls".execute()` returns a `Process` object which is why `"ls".execute().text` works. You should be able to just read the error stream to determine if there were any errors.

There is a extra method on `Process` that allow you to pass a `StringBuffer` to retrieve the text: `consumeProcessErrorStream(StringBuffer error)`.

Example:

```
def proc = "ls".execute()
def b = new StringBuffer()
proc.consumeProcessErrorStream(b)

println proc.text
println b.toString()
```

Comment: It is not working with Bourn Again Shell script !#/bin/bash,

Comment: If working with bash scripts, you you probably invoke bash as part of the command : "/bin/bash script".execute()

Answer (score 40):

I find this more idiomatic:

```
def proc = "ls foo.txt doesnotexist.txt".execute()
assert proc.in.text == "foo.txt\n"
assert proc.err.text == "ls: doesnotexist.txt: No such file or directory\n"
```

As another post mentions, these are blocking calls, but since we want to work with the output, this may be necessary.

Answer (score 38):

```
// a wrapper closure around executing a string                                  
// can take either a string or a list of strings (for arguments with spaces)    
// prints all output, complains and halts on error                              
def runCommand = { strList ->
  assert ( strList instanceof String ||
           ( strList instanceof List && strList.each{ it instanceof String } ) \
)
  def proc = strList.execute()
  proc.in.eachLine { line -> println line }
  proc.out.close()
  proc.waitFor()

  print "[INFO] ( "
  if(strList instanceof List) {
    strList.each { print "${it} " }
  } else {
    print strList
  }
  println " )"

  if (proc.exitValue()) {
    println "gave the following error: "
    println "[ERROR] ${proc.getErrorStream()}"
  }
  assert !proc.exitValue()
}
```

Comment: +1 This shows the output incrementally as the output is generated..which is extremely important for a long running process

Comment: To use this solution, issue the following line: `runCommand("echo HELLO WORLD")`

Comment: @mholm815 how can we approve required scripts from pipeline itself?

Comment: @RNK: [He left](https://stackoverflow.com/users/959352/mholm815) approx. 2017: *"Last seen more than 6 years ago"*

Answer (score 27):

To add one more important piece of information to the previous answers:

For a process

```
def proc = command.execute();
```

always try to use

```
def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
//proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

rather than

```
def output = proc.in.text;
```

to capture the outputs after executing commands in Groovy as the latter is a blocking call ([SO question for reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300550/difference-in-collecting-output-of-executing-external-command-in-groovy)).

Answer (score 8):

```
def exec = { encoding, execPath, execStr, execCommands ->

    def outputCatcher = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def errorCatcher = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    def proc = execStr.execute(null, new File(execPath))
    def inputCatcher = proc.outputStream

    execCommands.each { cm ->
        inputCatcher.write(cm.getBytes(encoding))
        inputCatcher.flush()
    }

    proc.consumeProcessOutput(outputCatcher, errorCatcher)
    proc.waitFor()

    return [new String(outputCatcher.toByteArray(), encoding), new String(errorCatcher.toByteArray(), encoding)]
}

def out = exec("cp866", "C:\\Test", "cmd", ["cd..\n", "dir\n", "exit\n"])

println "OUT:\n" + out[0]
println "ERR:\n" + out[1]
```

Comment: I am really annoyed that a person took the time to give an answer and someone just downvoted it for no apparent reason. if this is a community, one should feel obligated to add a comment (unless it's a very obvious reason that any competent programmer would immediately see) explaining the downvote.

Comment: @AmosBordowitz Lots of answers get downvotes. It's okay, it's one downvote. That said, it could be because it's code with no word of explanation -- not always well-received.

Comment: @ChrisBaker so why not point it out? You yourself are not positive that this is the reason..

Comment: @AmosBordowitz I am not the official downvote explainer, I cannot tell you why not, and it's understandable that I'm not certain since we're talking about an action taken by another individual. I offered one possibility. Why not explain the downvote, sure, why not explain the code in the answer? At any rate, I'm sure we'll all be okay.

Comment: @ChrisBaker we obviously have very different views on what a community should actually look like..

Comment: @AmosBordowitz p.s. explaining downvotes is not compulsory for very specific reasons that the community has hashed out over years of discussion, but I guess you know better.

Comment: @ChrisBakerI never made any such claim ("but I guess you know better"). It's a decency thing, not a knowledge thing..

Comment: @Amos Bordowitz: Does it actually answer the question? Many code dump answers are completely bogus (but no one bothers to check them). The question says *"other than creating a bunch of code to create two threads to read both inputstreams"*. Isn't that what is being implemented here (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen whoa. brought that one back to life haha. Yes, I have since learned these points. I was a newbie then.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing emles-kz's answer

```
def exec(encoding, execPath, execStr, execCommands) {
    def outputCatcher = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def errorCatcher = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def proc = execStr.execute(null, new File(execPath))
    def inputCatcher = proc.outputStream

    execCommands.each { cm ->
        inputCatcher.write((cm + '\n').getBytes(encoding))
        inputCatcher.flush()
    }
  
    inputCatcher.write('exit\n'.getBytes(encoding))
    inputCatcher.flush()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(outputCatcher, errorCatcher)
    proc.waitFor()
    return [new String(outputCatcher.toByteArray(), encoding), new String(errorCatcher.toByteArray(), encoding)]
}

// On Mac or Linux
def out = exec("utf-8", "/", "/bin/sh", ["echo 'test\n'", "ls", "cd usr", "echo", "ls"])

// On Windows
def out = exec("utf-8", "C:", "cmd", ["cd..", "dir"])

println "OUT:\n" + out[0]
println "ERR:\n" + out[1]
```

[jenkins groovy test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqE3s.png)

Answer (score -7):

```
command = "ls *"

def execute_state=sh(returnStdout: true, script: command)
```

but if the command fails, the process will terminate.

Comment: Where does `sh` come from?

Comment: `sh` is part of the Jenkins groovy DSL. Probably not useful here

Comment: Jenkins Groovy DSL != Groovy

Comment: as others have stated, this is part of the Jenkins DSL

Comment: This answer is not applicable to the question that was asked.

Comment: Only valid for jenkins