# How to run python commands using groovy in Jenkins slaves' Script Console?

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy

I need to run something arbitrary as simple as `python -c "print('hello')"` on one of the Jenkins' slaves' Script Console. Here's what I'm trying:

```
def cmd = 'python -c "print(\'hello\')"'
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println "out> $sout\nerr> $serr"
```

However, getting empty output:

```
out> 
err>
```

Is there a way to grab python's output in Groovy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to divide command into array

```
def cmdArray = ["python", "-c", "print('hello')"]
def cmd = cmdArray.execute()
cmd.waitForOrKill(1000)
println cmd.text
```

Not sure why your version does not work.

Comment: i suspect python creates child process to run code, which (child process) can't be tracked by groovy... but this is just my guess. not sure how one can check it though.

Answer (score 4):

this works perfect for me:

```
def cmd = 'python -c "print(\'hello\')"'
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
```

use "Execute Groovy script" (not "Execute system groovy script")

Comment: this gives me: `out> 
err> 
return code: 0
stderr: 
stdout: `

Comment: are you using Execute SYSTEM Groovy script instead of Execute Groovy script? (I edited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

#### Groovy executing shell & python commands

To add one more important information to above provided answers is to consider the `stdout` and `stderr` for the **python** cmd or script that its being executed.

**Groovy** adds the `execute` method to make executing shells fairly easy, **eg:** `python -c` cmd:

```
groovy:000> "python -c print('hello_world')".execute()
===> java.lang.UNIXProcess@2f62ea70
```

But if you like to get the `String` associated to the cmd **standard output** (`stdout`) and/or an **standard error** (`stderr`), then there is no resulting **output** with the above cited code.

So in order to get the **cmd output** for a Groovy exec process always try to use:

```
String bashCmd = "python -c print('hello_world')"
def proc = bashCmd.execute()
def cmdOtputStream = new StringBuffer()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(cmdOtputStream, System.err)
print cmdOtputStream.toString()
```

rather than

```
def cmdOtputStream = proc.in.text
print cmdOtputStream.toString()
```

In this way we capture the outputs after executing commands in Groovy as the latter is a blocking call ([check ref for reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300550/difference-in-collecting-output-of-executing-external-command-in-groovy)).

#### Complete Example w/ `executeBashCommand` func

```
String bashCmd1 = "python -c print('hello_world')"
println "bashCmd1: ${bashCmd1}"
String bashCmdStdOut = executeBashCommand(bashCmd1)
print "[DEBUG] cmd output: ${bashCmdStdOut}\n"


String bashCmd2 = "sh aws_route53_tests_int.sh"
println "bashCmd2: ${bashCmd2}"
bashCmdStdOut = executeBashCommand(bashCmd2)
print "[DEBUG] cmd output: ${bashCmdStdOut}\n"

def static executeBashCommand(shCmd){
    def proc = shCmd.execute()
    def outputStream = new StringBuffer()
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
    return outputStream.toString().trim()
}
```

**Output**

```
bashCmd1: python -c print('hello_world')
[DEBUG] cmd output: hello_world
bashCmd2: sh aws_route53_tests_int.sh
[DEBUG] cmd output: hello world script
```

**NOTE1:** As shown in the above code (`bashCmd2`) example for a more complex python scripts you should execute it through a `.sh` bash shell script.

**NOTE2:** All examples have been tested under

```
$ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.4.11 JVM: 1.8.0_191 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```