# Running an external program from Katalon's Groovy / Java test case

Tags: java, groovy, command-line-interface, katalon-studio

In my Katalon project (running on Windoes OS), I like to run an external `python` program.

I was looking at several examples of how to execute an external program from a [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java) or [Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540608/how-to-run-python-commands-using-groovy-in-jenkins-slaves-script-console) program.

The problem is that no matter what program I try to run (the python script or even a simple `cd` command), I get the following error from `Katalon-Studio`:

```
[ERROR]  - Test Cases/CallPython FAILED because (of) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here are some of the options I tried:

**Groovy:**

```
println "python myp.py".execute().text
println "cd".execute().text
```

**Java**

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python myp.py");
String[] cmd = ["python", "myp.py"];
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd");
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run cd?

Comment: I'm trying to run `cd` just to see that I can run an external system command from the Katalon studio.

Comment: `cd` is a system command on most operating systems... For Windows you'd need "CMD /c cd" I think

Answer (score 0):

If everything has good HOME_PATH this code should help

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "python myp.py")
Process process = pb.start()
```