# How do I execute shell script from Jenkins groovy script in the parameters option?

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins

I want to call a shell script in the Uno-Choice Dynamic Reference Parameter
and perform some operation (create some files and call some other shell
scripts from the called shell script) .

As of now I am able to call shell script and cat some files but I am not able
to create new files  or call another shell script from within this.

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()

// 1) 
def proc ='cat /home/path/to/file'.execute()
//display contents of file

// 2) 
def proc="sh /home/path/to/shell/script.sh".execute()
//to call a shell script but the above dosent work if I echo some contents
//into some file.

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
return sout.tokenize()
```

eg:- in `script.sh` if  I add line

```
echo "hello world" > test
```

then test file is not created

for more understanding:

[Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands)

http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Executing-a-shell-python-command-in-Jenkins-Dynamic-Choice-Parameter-Plugin-td4711174.html

Comment: what does not work? traces, errors, ...?

Comment: Try `sh echo "hello world" > test` or even better `echo "hello world" > /tmp/test` in case it was working but you just couldn't find the file.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian.
But its too not working.

Comment: Make sure you search file in a proper location. Try using an absolute path and check the Jenkins master's filesystem. In Jenkins groovy is usually executed on master.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you are running the bash scripts from a groovy wrapper, the stdout and stderr are already redirected to the groovy wrapper. In order to override this, you need to use `exec` within a shell script.

for example:

the groovy script:

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()

def proc ='./script.sh'.execute()

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println sout
```

The shell script named `script.sh` and is located in the same folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test redirect"
```

Running the groovy with the shell script above will produce the output `Test redirect` on the stdout of the groovy script

Now add stdout redirection with `exec` in  the script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1>/tmp/test
echo "Test redirect"
```

Now running the groovy script will create a file `/tmp/test` with a content `Test redirect`

You can read more about I/O redirection in bash [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)