# execute shell command from groovy script

Tags: java, linux, shell, groovy, execute

```
import com.hp.opr.api.scripting.Event;
import com.hp.opr.api.scripting.Priority;
import com.hp.opr.api.scripting.Severity;
import com.hp.opr.api.ws.model.event.ci.OprNode;
import com.hp.ucmdb.api.*
import com.hp.ucmdb.api.topology.*
import java.util.List;


class SimpleExample
{
                def init()
                {
                                // Nothing to initialize
                }

                def destroy()
                {
                                // Nothing to destroy
                }

                def process(List<Event> events)
                {
                                events.each {
                                                event -> modifyEvent(event); 
                                }
                }

                def modifyEvent(Event event)
                {

                                String title = event.getTitle()
                                String sev = event.getSeverity()
                                event.setDescription(title+sev)

                                String command = "sh /opt/HP/BSM/bin/snmp_trap_test.sh"
                                def proc = command.execute()
                                StringBuffer sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
                                proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
                                proc.waitForOrKill(15000)




                }
}
```

hello everyone, 
i am totally new to groovy scripting
i need to execute a script on Linux using groovy,

i need to run a script located on linux.
i found the above code and i tried to use it but it is not working

what is wrong with my code here.

Comment: CopyPasting code from google is not how learning a new programming language works. Start with some easy tasks like "output hello world!" In your example you do not call "main".

Comment: hello alexander, it is not copy paste. this is my code after adding it to my script.

Comment: See point 3 in http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy executing shell commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands)

Comment: the script runs correctly as the description is set to title+sev as mentioned in event.setDescription(title+sev) ,, but the problem is the command that run the script is not correct as i think