# How to use GIT commands (diff, log, etc.) in Groovy script (windows)

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I just started learning DevOps and have a query. It might be very basic so please don't mind.

Setup:
Jenkins, GIT, Groovy, Java are installed on single windows server.

My Goal is to write a Groovy script which will do following:
1. Execute GIT commands (on local GIT repository) to pull some data (result).
2. Take further actions based on above result.

Query: How to execute GIT commands in Groovy script? What all is needed? Would be great if someone can please share a sample basic script.

Comment: look [jgit](https://grails.org/plugin/jgit) or [grgit](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit)

Comment: Are u going to use jenkins#pipeline ?

Comment: @daggett - Eventually Yes! Expectation is to invoke this script from Jenkins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a broader spectrum, what you want to achieve is just call linux commands from groovy, now regarding that:

There are 3 ways out of this, either you can just call the git commands from a shell script (since i understand you want to use jenkins for this), use some sort of git jenkins plugin, or if you absolutely want to use groovy for it, you can take a look at this question [Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands) , to summarize, you can do the following:

```
def proc = "git command args".execute()
def b = new StringBuffer()
proc.consumeProcessErrorStream(b)

println proc.text
println b.toString()
```

on b you would have the errors of executing the linux command if there were any,

Best Regards,

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Able to run git commands in Groovy script using code you shared. :) Just a quick query: currently my git repository resides on same machine as groovy, so I was able to run following git command: git --git-dir="C:/GIT/New/.git" diff .. How do I execute same when my git repository resides on a remote/different windows machine?

Comment: thanks a lot. I was able to run git commands in Groovy script using code you shared. :) 

Just a quick query: currently my git repository resides on same machine as groovy, so I was able to run following git command: def proc = "git --git-dir="C:/GIT/New/.git" diff".execute() .. 

How do I execute same when my git repository resides on a remote/different windows machine?

Comment: you just prepend "ssh user@yourremoteserver" inside the string that containes the git command, bear in mind that you are dealing with linux commands now, also, please accept the answer if it worked :D

Comment: Juan Sebastian: Sure, I will try that and get back. :)

Comment: you would need to set up ssh keys between the servers before this can work, check this out https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Answer (score 2):

check jenkins pipeline examples

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/

simplest pipeline with git:

```
node {
    stage('Clone sources') {
        git url: 'https://github.com/jfrogdev/project-examples.git'
    }
}
```

git pipeline plugin doc:

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i will try this as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Jenikins>manageJenkins>Script Console

execute following command

println(["git","--version"].execute().text)