# groovy assign map based on shell script

Tags: groovy

I have a bash script that returns something like this:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

I need to get those values saved as a map in groovy. How do I get that returned value stored as a groovy map?

Comment: what do You mean "bash returns" ?

Comment: The bash script prints out exactly what is in the code block.

Comment: any problems with this? http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to try something like this:

```
File script = new File('<My_Script_Path>')
def rawJson = script.getText().execute()
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = jsonSlurper.parseText(rawJson)
```

`result` should then be structured like your map above.

For more reference, see these links...

[Groovy & JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

[This answer showcases running a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159270/8160553)

Answer (score 0):

You should just need

```
def out = "script.sh".execute().text
def map = new JsonSlurper().parseText(out)
```