# Jenkins: Run a curl command within groovy scrpt

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a requirement where I need to send the status of the jenkins slave to influxdb. To do so I need to run a curl command from Jenkins Groovy script.

My script looks like this :

```
int value=0;
for (Node node in Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
   if (!node.toComputer().online){
   value=1;
   }
   else{
   value=0;
   }

curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/write?db=jenkins_db&u=user&p=pass --data-binary 'mymeas,tag=$node.nodeName status=$value'
```

But after running the script values do not appear in influxdb.
Any Idea what might be wrong here?

PS I also tried

```
def response = [ 'bash', '-c', "curl", "-i", "-XPOST", "http:/localhost:8086/write?db=jenkins_db&u=user&p=pass", "--data-binary", "\'mymeas tag=$node.nodeName status=$value"\' ].execute().text
```

Comment: you have to check the error output (stderr). by using `...execute().text` you partially get stdout.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands

Comment: I run the script from a console provided at https://jenkinsurl/script
There is no output printed.

Comment: do you mean `println "hello world"` not printing output? which plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to echo your curl command

`echo curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/write?db=jenkins_db&u=user&p=pass --data-binary 'mymeas,tag=$node.nodeName status=$value'`