# How to write shell script to Check URL is up and post it in Email in jenkins freestyle project

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins

I am trying to write a script which can checking a URL is up and then post the console output in email stating like "200 ok" site is up
Scenario 2: Will only trigger email once site is down

What is wrong in the below code

```
def msgbody='200 OK'

if ((curl -Is https://google.com | head -1) == '$msgbody')
   echo ==========Success
) else (
   echo ==========Fail
  )
  fi    (What is wrong in this code)
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is not for questions about technologies or to find somebody doing the work for free (search some freelance service for that). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with looking at the URL class. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html

That will allow you to read the whole page under a certain URL using `getText()`. If the page is down, this will throw an exception.

Jenkins should then automatically fail the job. In the Jenkins job definition, you can specify when and how to send a Mail.

**EDIT** This isn't valid Groovy: `(curl -Is https://google.com | head -1)`. Groovy can't run shell commands or build pipes with `|` like BASH does. Also, you have to use `{}` around the then/else blocks after the if, not `()`. Lastly, there is no `fi` in Groovy:

```
 if (condition) {
     ...then...
 } else {
     ...
 }
```

See [Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands) for how to run shell commands from Groovy scripts.

Not that you have to examine the result of `exitValue()` to determine whether the command failed. `0` is success.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron .. this is helpful.. I am new to Jenkins but this is awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as a Windows Batch (you need to install curl and configure it in the PATH):

```
@echo off
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail http://domain-or-ip/context
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
   echo ==========Success
) else (
   echo ==========Fail
   exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolás Santisteban

Comment: @AdityaRanjan No problem! If this works for you don't forget to mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: If you go through the trouble of installing curl, then you can also optimize to send just a HEAD request: https://serverfault.com/questions/340188/using-curl-to-make-a-head-request-with-a-hard-timeout?rq=1
That way, you can check only whether the site is up without download all the data.