# How to capture shell script output using groovy from soap ui?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am able to execute Shell script command Soap UI and not sure how to read and store the echo output to a variable.

`test1.sh` contains below commands

```sh
CURRENTDATEONLY=`date +"%b %d, %Y"`
echo Current Date is: ${CURRENTDATEONLY}
sleep 10
```

I am able to execute Shell script command Soap UI and not sure how to read and store the echo output to a variable.

```
I have tried below code, still not capturing the output.
def command = "C:/Program Files (x86)/PuTTY/putty.exe -ssh user@ip -pw pass  -m C:/test1.sh"

def Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor()

BufferedReader is1 =   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
log.info is1
        String line; 

        // reading the output 
        while ((line = is1.readLine()) != null) 

     log.info line ;
====================================================
Tried using jsch api as well, but no luck

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

        String user = "";
        String pw = "";
        String host = "";
        int port = 22;
        String remoteFile = "C:/test1.sh";

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            session.setPassword(pw);
            //session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            log.info("Establishing Connection...");
            session.setTimeout(60000);
            session.connect();
            log.info("Connection established.");
            log.info("Crating SFTP Channel.");
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
            sftpChannel.connect();
            log.info("SFTP Channel created.");

            InputStream inputStream = sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)) 
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    log.info(line);
                }

        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Expectation is to read and store `CURRENTDATEONLY` variable to properties

Comment: there are a lot of questions `read process output`. example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands

Comment: i have tried using getInputStream from Process class and still not able to capture the output.

Comment: could you run the putty from windows console (cmd)? do you see output in windows console?

Comment: Yes, able to run from cmd and getting output in console

Comment: i mentioned `windows console` and not a putty console. i believe putty starts it's own console and windows console can't read it.

Comment: Yes you are right, i tried through cmd by using below entry and everything printed on putty console.                                                                                                                          C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY>putty.exe -ssh user@ip -pw passeord  -m C:/test1.sh