# Error while executing another process through Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm invoking another process through Groovy script of Jenkins pipeline. Following is simple one script -

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx}
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'pwd'
                    def path = "pwd".execute().text
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`sh 'pwd'` works perfectly fine. However `"pwd".execute().text` results into following error -

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods.execute(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:533)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$895.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pwd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProcessGroovyMethods.execute(ProcessGroovyMethods.java:533)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$895.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:8)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor685.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

`sh` - starts shell and under shell runs the command `pwd`.

`"pwd".execute()` tries to run program `pwd`  and  if it's not in PATH then you have the error "The system cannot find the file specified"

as soon as [`pwd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwd) is a command built into a shell (it's not an executable) - you can't run it without shell.

to reproduce `sh` behavior in groovy code you could use this

```
['sh','-c','pwd'].execute().text
```

but beware. there is a possibility, that process you've started with `.execute()` not yet printed the output and you already tried to get result `.text`.

[Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands)

Comment: Thanks daggett for answer. As you suggested, I tried `['sh','-c','pwd'].execute()` and also `['/bin/bash','-c','pwd'].execute()`. But both are resulting into error cannot run program.

Comment: In my query pipeline code, I had used agent in `agent {label 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx'}` which was linux machine and even if I wrap `script` in stage with `nod(linux-machine)` to execute code on that machine. Still linux commands were giving error - `cannot run program xyz` whic is surprising. Later I realized that this code was being executed on Jenkins master which is weird and my Jenkins master is Windows machine. Strange behaviour :(

Comment: @Alpha - same problem here - but more in the focus than in the fine line comments.
i really have to suspect that sh and execute are opening a set of quite different contexts. the second is reporting "/" for 'pwd' whilst i am getting the expected workdir for 'sh'. i was using the 'set' command without any trouble.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902824/using-sh-vs-execute-in-a-jenkins-groovy-shared-library-design-switches-be