# How to remove file using a task gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, terminal

I'm trying to remove a file using a gradle task

```
task remove {
    exec {
        working dir file/file2
        commandLine 'myFirstCommandLineWhichWorks'
        commandLine "rm", "'myFile.txt'"
    }
}
```

and I got error "A problem occurred starting process 'command 'rm'"

Note: I don't want to use `task something(type: Delete)` and no external scripts.
it must be from commandLine.
There is a possibility ?

Comment: Would you happen to be on Windows?

Comment: yes I have windows

Comment: Windows doesn't support `rm` - maybe if you run it from mingw or the likes, but you don't have access to UNIX tools. You'll need to use a Windows-specific command, but as I highly recommend using Groovy's built-in functions for the sake of portability.

Comment: Have you tried `file('myFile.txt').delete()`?

Comment: @cfrick "it must be from commandLine"

Answer (score 2):

Gradle provides both a task type ([`Delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html)) and a method ([`delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#delete-java.lang.Object...-)) for this use case.

> Note: I don't want to use `task something(type: Delete)`

Why? If you don't want to use Gradle functionality, then don't use Gradle at all.

> it must be from commandLine.

As others have mentioned, the command `rm` is not available on Windows systems. This is one of the reasons why this functionality gets abstracted by Gradle.

---

There is another problem with your code: You define a Gradle task that is completely irrelevant, as it won't execute any functionality. Gradle distinguishes between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*. The `<code>` inside the closure of a task definition `task <name> { <code> }` will be executed directly (during configuration phase). Only (internal) task actions, `doFirst` and `doLast` closures are executed when the actual task is executed (either from command line or as a task dependency).

To solve this problem, either use a task of type `Delete` directly (you should do this anyway), use a task of type `Exec` or wrap the `exec` method in a `doFirst` / `doLast` closure:

```
task remove(type: Delete) {
    delete 'myFile.txt'
}

task remove(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'del', 'myFile.txt', '/q'
}

task remove {
    doFirst {
        exec {
            commandLine 'del', 'myFile.txt', '/q'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows you should use command "del /q" instead of "rm"

```
task remove {

   exec {

   working dir file/file2
   commandLine 'myFirstCommandLineWhichWorks'
   commandLine "del /q", "'myFile.txt'"

   }

}
```

As I mentioned in comments, I would suggest to use Groovy for deleting files, because executing environment specific commands from command line we are loosing the interoperability, so when you switch the environment to Mac or Linux the command won't work anymore. Also try maybe with this piece of code which I've got from this SO post: [Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands)

```
task remove {

    def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
    def proc = 'del myFile.txt /q'.execute()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
    println "out> $sout err> $serr"

}
```

And with plain groovy method it should be super simple:

```
task remove { 
    String filename = "myFile.txt"  
    boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted =  new File(filename).delete()  
    println fileSuccessfullyDeleted 
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I got "A problem occurred starting process 'command 'del /q"

Comment: Why can't you just use Groovy to actually just delete the file? Why it has to be the command line?

Comment: Might have to be `"del", "/q", "'myFile.txt'"`

Comment: Yeah, or even `"del", "'myFile.txt'", "/q"`

Comment: Mainly meant that I'm not entirely sure Groovy is fine with a space in there, and therefore surrounds it in quotes, making the terminal interpret "del /q" as an executable rather than del with a parameter /q. I have no idea though, I'm by no means this familiar with Groovy, nor have I ever used `commandLine` in Groovy before.

Comment: Now I got `A problem occurred starting process 'command 'del"`

Comment: @Zoe I mean by using the command line directly from groovy code we loose all of the interoperability, so when you execute this Windows code on Linux or Mac it won't work anymore. And with plain Groovy it should work in all environments

Comment: and what would the removal using groovy look like?

Comment: but now using groovy, how it will be know where my files is ? what path to this file ?

Comment: So pass the filePath via the argument

Comment: Each task definition in this answer is completely irrelevant, because their functionality is executed during *configuration phase*. The file will be deleted each time `gradle` is invoked (with any task names as arguments).