# Do I need proc.out.close() (groovy execute shell command)?

Tags: groovy

Based on:

[Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands)

I have this groovy script:

```
def proc = "some bash command".execute()

//proc.out.close() // hm does not seem to be needed...
proc.waitFor()

if (proc.exitValue()) {
  def errorMsg = proc.getErrorStream().text
  println "[ERROR] $errorMsg"
} else {
  println proc.text
}
```

That I use the execute various linux bash commands. Currently it works fine even without the `proc.out.close()` statement.

What is the purpose of `proc.out.close()` and why is it (not?) needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proc.text` is actually `proc.getText()`

form groovy api doc: Read the text of the output stream of the Process. Closes all the streams associated with the process after retrieving the text.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#getText()

So, when using `proc.text` you don't need to call `proc.out.close()`