# Build Gradle: git branch retuns null

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am trying to fetch the branch the current git head is in as:

```
String branchName = gitBranchName().toLowerCase()

String gitBranchName() {
    def branch = System.env.GIT_BRANCH
    if (!branch){
        // For local build
        def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
        proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
        proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
        proc.waitFor()
    }
    return branch
}
```

on running this it always returns null and hence code breaks when executing `gitBranchName().toLowerCase()` as toLowerCase() throws error on running for null.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':init_env'.
> Cannot invoke method toLowerCase() on null object
```

I guess it is sending the value of branch returned from System.env.GIT_BRANCH which is not set on local machine and it is not waiting for the if block to complete.

Any idea what is wrong and why?

Comment: 'I guess it is sending the value of branch returned from System.env.GIT_BRANCH which is not set on local machine and it is not waiting for the if block to complete.'- Looks like you answered your own question.

Comment: Are you sure the `if` block is ever entered?

Comment: @AshutoshVaish yeah may be, but then how do I make it work? I am already using proc.waitFor()

Comment: @Koenigsberg yes it goes inside the IF block

Comment: Try restarting your IDE and system after you have set the environment variable.

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with Git (except that you're running a Git command to produce some output) and almost everything to do with Groovy, which is a downright weird language. See [Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159148/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `org.ajoberstar.grgit` Gradle plugin with success:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '5.0.0' apply false
}

import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

Grgit git = Grgit.open currentDir:project.rootDir
String commit = git.head().abbreviatedId
```